# Alternatives to GZIPInput/OutputStream with better compression ratios?

Tags: java, stream, compression

I need to store abitrary binary data (essentially files of various common formats, JPEG, PDF, MS-Office and some other odd files). Slow compression is not a problem, but I'm looking for reasonably fast decompression and as good a compression ratio as I can get.

For now my system immediately stores the data uncompressed and a daemon attempts to compress the data later, for now the only option I have implemented is using GZIP. If the file can be compressed it is transparently replaced with a compressed version by the daemon (thats why slow compression does not bother me at all). If there were more options I would be quite happy to let the daemon try all the choices and go with the one that yields the best compression.

To keep the system simple, I don't want to go through great lengths to integrate stuff that does not support use through the Stream API (like 7-Zip LZMA). Are there any compression implementations beside the GZIP one provided by the JRE that might be useful? FOS preferred.

Comment: Just an FYI, JPEG and PDF are already compressed as-is, doing some extra gzip compression on these kind of files will not compress them significantly more.

Comment: Yes, compressing those files might even be growing them. A good implementation could filter by extension and leave those already compressed files alone.

Comment: Yes JPEG generally compress poorly due to their already compressed nature, but I see no reason treat them on a different code path. Surprisingly even GZIP still takes of 2-5% from most JPEG's, presumably because of there is a thumbnail and some uncompressed meta data in the file. PDF's that do not contain images usually compress quite well (almost like text files).

Comment: PDF should use LZW stream for text but I might be well outdated, it has been long time since I looked into the format. You can use Deflater/Inflater input streams w/ max compression (gzip doesn't use max) to squeeze few more bytes. The default settings (512 bytes buffer) for GZipOutStream make it quite inefficient for large files.

Comment: It seems to depend on the application that created the PDF. In smaller text-only PDF's there seems to be much plaintext fluff left that compresses well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another LZMA implementation in pure Java: [XZ for Java](http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html) (includes LZMA).

Answer (score 3):

You could giva a try to the bzip lib. bzip usually has better compression ratios at speed expense. Some implementations below:

http://www.kohsuke.org/bzip2//

http://code.google.com/p/jbzip2/

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/BZip2format.htm

There is also an implementation of bzip on the apache commons compress lib:

http://commons.apache.org/compress/

Comment: After some testing with the apache implementation (from the first link, but according to version information all apache implementations seem to be the same/based on the same), I can only say that the JRE provided GZIP seems to beat it in every case (compression ratio, didn't measure speed).

Comment: The implementation in the second link seems to be an independend port, but the compression ratios turned out to be practically identical in my short test.

Comment: On any kind of file? Large ones?

Comment: I used a 221KB doc file, GZIP compressed down to 153KB, BZIP2 resulted in 156KB. Although that is pretty close, I scrapped my integration of BZIP2 and did not investigate further (I got my hands on a pure Java LZMA2 implementation that suits my requirements better).

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution working for you but I think that testing with a single doc file is not a very good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [LZMA](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html). It looks like someone implmeneted usage with streams [here](http://contrapunctus.net/league/haques/lzmajio/).

Comment: The whole idea with independet processes and stuff does not really induce trust in that solution. Also, I found a more "native" implementation of LZMA.